# Cannot get css button to display correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 and trying to get a simple transparent button look like on getbootstrap website home page. using the following code is giving me the default bootstrap button look with the gradient in the background instead of the look I am going for. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is the CSS:

```
.btn-outline{color:#540300;background-color:transparent;border-color:#540300;}
.btn-outline:hover,.btn-outline:focus,.btn-outline:active{color:#fff;background-color:#540300;border-color:#333;}
```

and my HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline" role="button">Test Button</a>
```

Comment: where do you see a transparent button? the [B]?

Comment: on the getbootstrap home page. The download button up top. The big one. I am trying to mimic that button style and cannot get it to work using the above code.

Comment: just make sure you're loading bootstrap's CSS first, then override with your styles. IF you can't, add !important to background-color and it should work

Comment: used !important and it still has the gradient, only now with onhover it turns transparent on the background but the button still looks the same with the gradient. I am loading bootstrap first, then my custom css last.

Comment: without my code above, can someone give a solution for me to replicate that type of button using bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised JS Fiddle [Revised fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/zpwcht43/4/)

```
    .btn {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10;
 -moz-border-radius: 10;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  color: #594080;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: solid #594080 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #594080;
 text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: without my code, does anyone know a solution for me to replicate that type of button using bootstrap 3?

Comment: that really doesnt look as clean as the one on the bootstrap page. And I want transparency to see the background through the button. Looking at the source code on the bootstrap page it does use transparency. Just not sure why it wont work on my page the same.

Comment: I'm looking at http://getbootstrap.com, no transparency used on the button there.

Comment: view page source, and look at their css file. It uses transparency.

Comment: Doesn't look like transparent is used visually. The background is white on hover and solid on active.

Comment: also look on the getting started page. There are the 3 buttons that are the same style. I am trying to replicate that style and cant get it right for some reason... looks easy but its driving me crazy...

Comment: Dude, look at http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/zpwcht43/3/ if this doesn't do it for you and you're unable to edit to your liking then I give up. I also inspected the transparency in the CSS on getboostrap, the style is there but not being used as it isn't set.

Comment: You're welcome I updated by answer please vote me up!